# How do I reinspect the dom after a jQuery load?

Tags: jquery, dom, load

Basically, I'm clicking a link -> loading it's content in a new-content div -> moving and removing the old content -> making the new content the current content.

I'm using the jquery load function. Of course the new content isn't seen by the dom given the way it was loaded. I had hoped using `#page a` would be the best since `#page` is a constant on the dom.

This works, obviously, with the first time the page loads but never after that.

I need jquery to recognize the click on the newly loaded content. I know this is possible but I can't quite find the way.

```
$('#page').append('<div id="new-content"></div>');
    $('#page a').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('click');
        var topHeight = $('.site-header').height();
        var comp = new RegExp(location.host);
        if(comp.test($(this).attr('href'))){
               // a link that contains the current host           
              e.preventDefault();
              var contentURL = $(this).attr('href');
              $('#new-content').load(contentURL+" #content",function(){
                    var newContent = $(this);
                    $('#content').first().animate({'left':'-100%'},function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                        newContent.find('#content').unwrap();
                        $('#page').append('<div id="new-content"></div>');
                        pageHeight = $('#content').height();
                        $('#slide-out').css({'height':pageHeight});
                    });
              }).css({'top':topHeight});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the delegated version of `on()`, like so :

```
$('#page').on('click', 'a', function(e){ ...
```